# Deep-linking via <div> block and attribute title='', and toggleClass 'selected'

Tags: jquery, deep-linking

Refer to jsfiddle demo that I have created [here](http://jsfiddle.net/m9tz7/), I'm trying to add in deep-linking features for my current client's website.

I need help with the following requirements:

My simple click toggleClass code:

```
$("div.contentBox").click(function () {

    var $this = $(this);
    // don't proceed if already selected
    var $previousSelected = $('.selected');
    if ( !$this.hasClass('selected') ) {
        $this.addClass('selected');
    }

    $previousSelected.removeClass('selected');  
});
```

(1) There will be many repetitive `<div class='contentBox'>` with each having different value for its attribute `title=''`

(2) Event trigger via `$("div.contentBox").click()` adding value from `title=''`, will churned out something like *http://site.com/index.html#content01-about-us*. Note: please provide sample coding how to achieve this.

(3) The reason of triggering event via `<div>` block instead of `<a>` is due to additional `<a>` tags inside of container `class='contentBox'`, and will eventually form nested `<a>` links, which is not allowed.

(4) `$("div.contentBox").click()` will also toggleClass 'selected'

(5) Returning from links, example *http://site.com/index.html#content01-about-us*, page load will be smart enough to get `<div class='contentBox' title='content01-about-us>` to addClass/toggle class `'selected'`

I had spent weeks figuring this out, but to no avail, desperately need help here. It would be best if anyone here kind enough to update the above jsfiddle [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/m9tz7/) as per requirement stated.

Been through some research myself and came across [history.js](https://github.com/balupton/History.js/), [address.js](http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/) and [BBQ plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/), but just couldn't get it to work

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need something like this:

```
$("div.contentBox").click(function () {

var $this = $(this);
// don't proceed if already selected
var $previousSelected = $('.selected');
if ( !$this.hasClass('selected') ) {
    $this.addClass('selected');
}
$previousSelected.removeClass('selected');  

if(location.href.indexOf('#') == -1)
  location.href += "#" + $(this).prop("title");
else
  location.href = location.href.split('#')[0] + "#" + $(this).prop("title");
alert(location.href);
});
```

And for second requirement:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if(location.href.indexOf('#') != -1){
    var page = location.href.split('#')[1];
    $("div[title*=" + page + "]").addClass('selected');
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, yes, 1st part requirement working, which is adding value from `title=''` to current url address via `location.href`. Now all is left is for return links, e.g. *http://site.com/index.html#some-link* to pick up corresponding `title=''`, for this example `title='some-link'` and toggleClass 'selected' to its parent `<div class='contentBox'>`

Comment: Thank you very much A.V, edited the code to <div> specified to `$("div[title*=" + page + "]").addClass('selected');` insted of `$("a[title*=" + page + "]").addClass('selected');`. You have surely saved my day